# Effects of ignoring random effects to type 1 error

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, mixed-model, p-value, repeated-measures

I was been told that failing to account for repeated measures can cause more type 1 errors, since sample sizes are over-counted. However, I simulated some data under mix effect model while ignore the random effects, the **p-value distribution looks skewed to 1, which is opposite to what I expected**.

Here is how I set up the simulation: We have control group and treatment group of taking a medication. Candidates are from 5 cities, and within each city, 3 people take the medication and 3 people take the placebo. Cities are modeled with random intercept, and medication are modeled as a fixed term. In multi-variate form, we have:
$$
y \sim MVN(\mathbf{X\beta, GG'\tau^2 + I\sigma^2})
$$

```
## create design matrix and block matrix
cities = paste0("City", rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 6))
RandM1 = model.matrix(~-1 + cities) %*% t(model.matrix(~-1 + cities))
RandM2 = diag(30)
FixM = cbind(Intercept = 1, Treatment = rep(c(0, 1), 15))


## set simulation parameters
beta0 = 1
beta1 = 0   # under the null hypothesis that medication is not effective
tau2 = 0.3
sigma2 = 0.2


## simulate outcome in multivariate form
pvals = c()
for (i in 1:1000){
  y = MASS::mvrnorm(n = 1, mu = FixM %*% c(beta0, beta1), Sigma = tau2 * RandM1 + sigma2 * RandM2)
  pvals[i] = summary(lm(y ~ 0 + FixM))$coefficients[2,4]
}


hist(pvals)
```

Under the null hypothesis(the medication has no effect, or $\beta_1 = 0$), we observed the distribution of p value as follow:

[image]

Why failing to count for random effect term can cause **deflated type 1 error, instead of inflated type 1 error**?

Comment: I haven't looked at your simulation, but type 1 errors (false positives) are caused by **deflated** p-values (p-values that are smaller than they should be). Your simulated p-values are **inflated** (leading to type 2 errors).

Comment: @Eoin Sorry for the confusion. When I say deflated p values, I actually mean p value shifts to 1. I will change my term to avoid confusion.

Comment: What does the p-value distribution look like when you model the random effects?

Comment: @BryanKrause Under the null hypothesis, p values should be uniformly distributed. I have tried to use likelihood ratio test, and indeed the p value is uniformly distributed.
`
pchisq(-2 * (logLik(lme4::lmer(y ~ 0 + FixM[,1] + (1|cities), REML = F)) - logLik(lme4::lmer(y ~ 0 + FixM + (1|cities), REML = F))), df = 1, lower.tail = F)
`

Comment: Yes, should be; was partly wondering if there was some error in your simulation code without digging in to it line-by-line.

Comment: @BryanKrause I prefer to use multi-variate form to simulate data, but it should be the same if you simulate random intercept separately.

Comment: I suspect part of the confusion here is that the random effects seem to be on the intercept term, while you're looking at the p-value for the slope term. I could be wrong, but I think ignoring random intercepts tends to increase type 2 errors (since that's residual variance you could be explaining) while ignoring random effects on the term you care about increases type 1 errors. I'm only going by memory though!

Comment: Interesting, maybe worth a simulation!

Comment: @Eoin You are right. I did another simulation, where I change the fix term to be $\beta_0$ only. I performed hypothesis testing on $\beta_0$, I indeed found inflated type 1 error.